# Which is better comparing with NULL or using NVL function?

Tags: sql, oracle

Which approach is better to get output of all the entries if the input is NULL or a specific record when input is NOT NULL? 
This is for PL/SQL on Oracle Database. Let me know if my first approach is wrong

`select * from student where (roll_no = :ROLL_NO or :ROLL_NO is NULL);`

OR

`select * from student where roll_no = NVL(:ROLL_NO, roll_no);`

Comment: What does better mean in your case?

Comment: Better means less time and space complexity, but I understood later that they can't be compared as they give different outputs

Answer (score 4):

The two approaches will give different results where `roll_no` is null, because `roll_no = roll_no` will not be true for those rows.

If there is an index, the optimiser has a special case for `somecol = nvl(:param,somecol)`, and you will see two `FILTER` operations and a `CONCATENATION` in the execution plan, representing the cases where `:param` is null or not null. Therefore I would use the `nvl` expression so long as `roll_no` is defined as a `NOT NULL` column.

Answer (score 1):

In general, using operators is a better approach.  This is because the optimizer can be smarter when the columns are not arguments to functions.

This answer assumes that `roll_no` is not `null`.

Although this could be a case that the Oracle optimizer sometimes catches, you might find that writing the query using `union all` actually produces a better execution plan when an appropriate index is present:

```
select s.*
from student s
where roll_no = :ROLL_NO
union all
select s.*
from student s
where :ROLL_NO is NULL;
```

Comment: As William Roberson points out (see his Answer), the two versions aren't even equivalent, so it doesn't really make sense to compare them. I would add that to your Answer. The correct version - depending on the OP's requirements - is probably the first one, and your `UNION ALL` alternative is for the first version (the correct one).

Answer (score 0):

Seconds approach would give same result with small modification(cannot compare null against null):

```
select * from student where NVL(roll_no,1) = NVL(NVL(:ROLL_NO, roll_no),1);
```

Answer (score 0):

William Robertson made a good point. I understood my mistake then. 
I tried the answer by Gordon linoff. It worked. 
I think waldemort's answer will also be true, but i didn't try it.

This answer below is what was my solution for it and it might be similar to waldemort's answer.

{`select * from student where AND (roll_no = nvl(roll_no,1) = nvl(:roll_no,1)`}

Thanks for the help guys